# SSH auto login different username

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to setup ssh auto-login using rsa keys on Raspberry PI (raspbian Jesse). Almost everything I find says to create keys on local machine (ssh-keygen), append the public key to the remote's .ssh/authorized_keys file and make sure that file's permissions set to 640 or 600.

I've done all that but still get prompted for password when ssh'ing.

I performed these actions on the **local** machine as user foo:

```
~$ cd .ssh
~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -t rsa (hit enter through all the prompts)
~/.ssh$ cat id_rsa.pub | ssh bar@remote.local 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
bar@remote.local's password: //prompted here
```

From another terminal that was already ssh'd to remote I verified that foo's public key was appended to bar's authorized_keys.

Tried ssh'ing as user foo to remote as user bar from a new terminal.

```
~$ ssh bar@remote.local
bar@remote.local's password: //prompted here
```

Auto login did not work.
So then I found this site http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html.
Followed the instructions and it works.
But this sounds opposite of what I would have thought. That site says to create the keys on the remote and append the public key to the remote's authorized_keys file then download the remote's private key to the local machine and use it as an identity file.

Is that correct? Why would someone want to cp a private key to another machine? I thought the private key should stay on the machine it was created for and should be protected.

Here are the instructions for the linked page in case it moves

```
On server:

cd .ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa  (hit return through prompts)
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
chmod 600 authorized_keys
rm id_rsa.pub

On client:

cd .ssh
scp myserver.com:.ssh/id_rsa myserver.rsa
chmod 600 myserver.rsa
echo "Host myserver" >> config
echo "Hostname reblets.com" >> config
echo "IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myserver.rsa" >> config
```

Comment: arghh!! found my problem. I had IdentityFile set to a different server's file for work and it wasn't using my local machine's identity file.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is (slightly) less secure as the private key exists in places it need not - but both do the same thing.

I wonder if you are running into an selinux + Redhat/Centos bug - which generally requires upgrading Centos with yum upgrade, then relabelling the filesystem (relabelling fixfiles or similar). You can check if this is the issue by temporarily disabling selinux.

Comment: updated question and tags with OS. (raspbian Jesse)

Comment: davidgo, thanks for the advice, I actually came across that in my searching for answer. I overlooked the fact that I had default IdentityFile pointing to a different rsa file. Found this out by using the -v option with ssh.